# lightweight-charts - How to show future times in advance?

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

How to show upcoming times with no data in lightweight-charts? Like the image below

[image]

Comment: I'd think you'd have to generate some meaningful data somehow

Comment: I can do that but how can I implement in this javascript library lightweight-charts?

Comment: by adding to the `lineSeries.setData` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate "future" points you can use [whitespace points](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/c84b12e5f7a97576902d9129decb3e8acbaf8e72/docs/whitespace-data.md). If you use them, `lightweight-charts` will display any time data but not price values/bars/candles.

Comment: Seems like the solution is working, but new problem arise now that's about updating the series data

Comment: Alright, so I have to add a second series with whitespaces. Problem solved.